# How to allow Chrome to run a plugin when viewing a local file while GPO restrictions are in place.

Tags: windows-server-2003, group-policy, google-chrome

The setup

- Windows server 2003 domain at a functional 2000 level
- Multiple server 2003 servers running terminal services
- All users running desktops delivered via RDP
- Google Chrome browser installed on the terminal servers and made accessible to the users
- Google Chrome group policy list in use
- Plugins are disabled by default via the GPO DefaultPluginsSetting

We have a situation where we are allowing plugins to be run by adding exceptions to the GPO PluginsAllowedForUrls. We have found a situation where Chrome is downloading a PDF and attempting to open it inside the browser. The location the PDF is being opened from shows in the URL bar as file:///D:/temp/myfilename.pdf. We have not found any variation of that URL that when put into the GPO PluginsAllowedForUrls will then allow Chrome to load the PDF via its internal PDF viewer. Does anyone know how to properly define the exception to allow this to work?

Thanks much,
D

Comment: Can you use the "*" wildcard to filter the local url? Also I hope you're planning your migration, 2003 goes EOL July 14 :/

Comment: Thus far file://* hasn't produced any usable results. And yes, that end of long term support looms closer every day.